# Do unordered lists respond to CSS transition?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBNtP/) is my JSFiddle.  What I'm trying to do is have a transition effect between two unordered lists.  When you click shop it takes you to the submenu.  When you click shop on  the submenu it takes you back to the main menu.  Why doesn't it slide or have any effect?  My goal is to transition the submenu from right to left, and have main menu transition left to right.  How can I make this work?

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <ul class="main-mobile-menu transition">
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="SHOP" data-menu-id="shop">SHOP</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="BRANDS" data-menu-id="brands">BRANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="ABOUT" >ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="CONTACT" >CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="shop-submenu" class="hide transition">
        <li><a href="#" title="SHOP" data-menu-id="main-mobile-menu">SHOP</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="ACCESSORIES" data-menu-id="accessories">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="ART" data-menu-id="art">ART</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="WOMENS" data-menu-id="womens">WOMENS</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="MENS" data-menu-id="mens">MENS</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" title="SHOES" data-menu-id="shoes">SHOES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="GIFT CERTIFICATE">GIFT CERTIFICATE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.mobile-nav{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.transition{
    -webkit-transition: none 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: none 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: none 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: none 0.4s ease;
    transition: none 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition-property: top, right, left, bottom, border;
    -moz-transition-property: top, right, left, bottom, border;
    -ms-transition-property: top, right, left, bottom, border;
    -o-transition-property: top, right, left, bottom, border;
    transition-property: top, right, left, bottom, border;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}

.open{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You can't transition `display`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the `display` property, but:

- `display` can't be transitioned
- you didn't include it in the list of properties you want to transition

Pick a property that [can be transitioned](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#animatable-css), change that instead of `display` and put it in the list you have set for `transition-property`.

Comment: @Mathias That makes sense, but I still can't make it work.  I've set #shop-submenu to left: 100px and .transition to left: 0px.  left is a property that can be transitioned, but nothing is happening.  See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBNtP/2/).

Comment: The property you transition has to be a property *that you change*. It has to go from value A to value B so that an animation of the values between A and B can be generated. You are still changing the `display` property. While you've assigned a `left` property, you never change it.

Comment: Brilliant, the light bulb is on.  I can figure out how to transition the elements from left or right.  Since pictures/demos speak a thousand words [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBNtP/5/) is the updated JSFiddle.  If you click on shop you will see the visibility transition from visible to hidden.  If you compare it with my original fiddle you'll see the differences in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want to achieve. The submenu has to come out of thin air from the right? Menu comes in from the left? Please explain yourself more thoroughly when you ask a question.

- It's not good semantics to make a different `ul` for every menu item you have and put them all under the main menu. You can nest a `ul` inside a `li`.
- If you have a class `.hide`, you don't need a class like `.open`. In jQuery just remove or toggle that class
- You can't just expect that an item makes an animation without you giving some input like a hover or a click. Read [this article on CSS-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) how to make an animation. You can edit a property in jquery and it wil animate itself if done correctly
- You've set `#shop-menu: left: 100px`. If you use `left` / `top` / `right` / `bottom` you need to set your element to either `absolute` or `relative`. [Read more about that here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ).
- You can replace `e.currentTarget` with `this` if you want

Comment: Since i can't put anymore links due to reputation. Here is a link to an updated fiddle with a slide effect. Done in pure jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/LBNtP/4/

Comment: Yes to both your questions.  If you want to see how it should work go [here](http://northamerica.triangl.com/), shrink your browser to mobile, and click on the menu button.  If you click around you'll see that the navigation menu slides from left to right and vice versa.